# Kafka - list empty consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Using a jmx client it is possibile to get the number of empty consumer groups, by calling this metric:

kafka.coordinator.group:name=NumGroupsEmpty,type=GroupMetadataManager

How to list which ones are empty with kafka-consumer-groups tool?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use Kafka admin client `listConsumerGroups()` method to get all consumers group ids, then use the result to to call `describeConsumerGroups()`, which returns a list of `ConsumerGroupDescription` (one for each requested consumer group id), each made of a list of `MemberDescription`.

So when processing that response, simply filtering the groups that currently have no members in them should yield the result you're looking for.

The admin client can be used in pretty much the same way as the consumer/producer clients: you build a java app, setup the appropriate permissions for it and point it to the cluster.

Here are the relevant API doc:

https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#listConsumerGroups--

https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#describeConsumerGroups-java.util.Collection-

Comment: If you are talking about what kafka-consumer-groups tool shows you, it doesn't match. If I run this script

$ ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server HOST:PORT --describe  --all-groups | grep -v TOPIC | grep -v ^$ | awk '{ if ( $7 == "-") groups[$1]++ } END{ for (group in groups) { print "Gruppo: " group  } }' | wc -l

the output is 80. Calling the bean value I get 17.

Comment: Hi. I'm not referring to the `kafka-consumer-group` CLI tool. The Admin Client is part of the Java or Python SDK => using it would require writing a small app. That could be as simple as a python script. Here is the doc for the Python Admin Client SDK: https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html